# Compare File Revision in DropBox API

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Is there any API in dropbox which can be used to get the metadata of the client side file. I want to download only those files from the server whose revision id has changed. So, I need to compare the existing file with the one of server. If they are same then dont download it if they are different then update it .

Answer (score 0):

This question is related:

[Locally calculate dropbox hash of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008040/localy-calculate-dropbox-hash-of-files)

Basically there doesn't seem to be a way to calculate the hash locally yourself, and AFAIK there's no API to the Dropbox native clients.

Instead you might want to look at the delta functionality in Dropbox's API.  It will provide you with a cursor that you can use to have Dropbox provide you with a list of only the files that have changed since your last update:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#delta

Answer (score 0):

@Ben:- thanks for the reply. I will try that. But I implemented the functionality by saving the file revision in a db and retrieving it when I next check for file info. If they are same then I forgo the download or else download the file and update its revision